# How to refresh angular service on a button click?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have data populated in the modal first time when i open it , so after saveChanges i empty out `questions` array now when i open modal again i see only last question not the new data as i am calling the service again on `openModal` it should get the new data or null not sure why `questions` still contain last element. Any idea ?

i wanted to empty `this.questions` array and call the `getData` service again when i open modal.

app.component.ts

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { isGeneratedFile } from '@angular/compiler/src/aot/util';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  data: any;
  questions: any[] = [];
  singleQuestion: any[] = [];
  showSaveButton: boolean = false;
  showNextButton: boolean = true

  constructor(private dataService:ApiService) {}

  openModal(){
    this.questions = this.dataService.getData();
    console.log('question modal', this.questions);
    if(this.questions.length){
      this.startFormatting();
    }
  }
  startFormatting() {
      this.showNextButton = true;
      this.singleQuestion = this.questions[0];
      this.showSaveButton = false; 
 }

 getNextQuestion(e: object){
  this.questions.shift();
   if(this.questions.length > 0){
      this.singleQuestion = this.questions[0];
      if(this.questions.length === 1) {
        this.showNextButton = false;
        this.showSaveButton = true;
    }
    }    
 }
 saveChanges(){
    this.questions = [];
    this.singleQuestion = [];
 }

}
```

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private data: any;
  private questions: any[];
  constructor() { }

  getData () {
    return this.data;
  }
  setData (_data:any) {
    this.data = _data;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you  create a stackblitz for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply save the data in service in the method "saveChanges()"  before you clean the values.

try

```
saveChanges() {
    this.dataService.setData(this.questions);
    this.questions = [];
    this.singleQuestion = [];
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cause no questions to be loaded when the modal is opened again? (++ I don't see any place that OP is *setting* values in the service.)

Comment: this.dataService.setData(this.questions);  this line set the date value in service.